# Integral question with a constant function resulting in solving a confusing equation

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

The question is: Let $f(x)= \int_0^{2a^3} \sin(\frac{x}{a})dx$, where $a$ is a positive constant less than 4. How many values of $a$ are there such that $f(x)^2=2f(x)$? (no calculator)

My problem comes from the "no calculator part". I think if I integrate $f(x)$ correctly I get $a-a\cos(2a^2)$. But if I set it equal to 2 ($a-a\cos(2a^2)-2=0$)  since $f(x)$ can equal either 0 or 2, I have no clue how to solve it without a calculator. Could someone help me figure out how to evaluate this?

Comment: Note that the question only asks for the *number* of possible values for $a$, not the exact values, so you could maybe try to find out the number of solutions to the equation by plotting the two sides of the equation.

Comment: Do you mean plot it without using a calculator? I'm not sure how I would do that precisely...

Comment: You don't need to do that precisely. Mostly, you just need to use properties of the functions, such as periodicity, intervals of monotonicity, and values at special points. For example the sine function goes from 0 to 1 monotonously in the interval $[0, \pi/2]$, so if any monotone decreasing function goes from some value larger than 1 to some value smaller than 1 in that interval, then there must be exactly one intersection.

Answer (score 2):

If you calculate the integral you get
$$f(x)=a\Big(1-\cos(2a^2)\Big) \mbox.$$
Now you want to solve:
$$a^2\Big(1-\cos(2a^2)\Big)^2=2a\Big(1-\cos(2a^2)\Big)$$
which becomes
$$a\cos^2(2a^2)+(2-2a)\cos(2a^2)+(a-2)=0$$
and solving for $\cos(2a^2)$ with the quadratic formula you get
$$\cos(2a^2)=\frac{2a-2\pm 2}{2a}$$
So the two solutions are: $1$ and $\frac{a-2}{2}$.

(i) If $\cos(2a^2)=1$, then $2a^2=2\pi k$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$,so $a=\sqrt{\pi k}$; but only when $a\le 4$, which means only when $\pi k \le 16$ (by hand you can see that $3,15\cdot 5 = 15,75$), so 5 solutions.

(ii) Now if $\cos(2a^2)=\frac{a-2}{a}$, you can graph the two functions of variable $a$ and see that they have only one solution and it is between $0$ and $2$.

In total 6 solutions.

I hope no mistakes were made.